# End of char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

I have such piece of code

```
int main()
{
    char* word = "kotok";
    char* word1 = word;
    while (word1 != '\0'){
        printf("%s ", word1);
        word1++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it doesn't end after printing "kotok, otok, tok, ok, k". This code continues prints some garbage and then stops. How to overcome it?

I tried to add `word1[strlen(word1)] = '\0';` but it gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: When you try the assignment, you are attempting to modify a string literal, which invokes 'undefined behaviour'.  A crash is a perfectly acceptable response to undefined behaviour; so is continuing as if nothing happened, or reformatting your disk, or …  (You could do a Google search for 'nasal daemons', or review [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behaviour](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).)  Don't invoke undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`word1` is a pointer. `'\0'` is a character. This is why `word1 != '\0'` doesn't do what you expect.

You have to dereference the pointer to get the character it points to:

```
while (*word1 != '\0') {
```

Answer (score 2):

`word1` is a pointer. Hence not null, zero

You need to change

```
while (word1 != '\0'){
```

to

```
while (*word1 != '\0'){
```

to deference the pointer

Answer (score 0):

Your logic where you are checking for the last character to match '\0'
is not working at all because "word1" is a pointer which points towards another pointer "word".

So it needs to be dereferenced with `*`.
Try changing

```
while (word1 != '\0')
```

To

```
while (*word1 != '\0')
```

This will solve your problem.